# GitLab Runner Installing vs Registering

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci-runner

I am quite confused on where the Gitlab CI/CD pipeline will build. I Installed GitLab Runner on my PC by following https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/. During the register, I needed to put down a URL in :

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com )
```

For this I put down https://gitlab.com. Is this mean that all the building and testing from my CI/CD pipeline will run on a server from GitLab? Or it is on my local computer where I installed GitLab Runner on?

Comment: Do you use gitlab server as SaaS offering hosted by Gitlab or do you manage your own instance ?

Comment: I did not manage my own instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you install and register the runner on your pc, the jobs will run locally. The runner will communicate with [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/).

If this is not the behavior you expect, you can use [Shared Runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/#shared-runners) provided by [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/)

Read more about Gitlab Runner [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/README.html)